# Having trouble getting Joda Time to work with my bukkit plugin

Tags: java, jodatime, bukkit

I am attempting to use Joda-Time with my bukkit plugin, however I am running into ClassNotFoundException and a NoClassDefFoundError.

I am using eclipse and have added it to my Build Path, and modified my Class-Path variable in my MANIFEST in the jar (and then adding the jar to a lib folder outside of my jar file), as well as tried to add the joda-time jar files in my jar file.

So make myself a bit more clear... The ClassNotFoundException shows up, when I add the files manually to my jar the NoClassDefFoundError shows up.

I've tried converting my project to maven (via eclipse) and added joda-time as a dependency to the pom.xml, but I cant seem to get that to work either (Maybe I'm doing something wrong).

If you need anymore information please ask. I'm not sure what else to include.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
    at com.**********.plugin.UMSBase.registerEvents(UMSBase.java:46)
    at com.***********.plugin.UMSBase.onEnable(UMSBase.java:22)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:381)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:282)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:264)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.j(MinecraftServer.java:303)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.e(MinecraftServer.java:282)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:242)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:150)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:381)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:573)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:80)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put Joda Time's jar file in the same folder as craftbukkit.jar.
I'm not sure if this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to build plugins maven-shade-plugin, which inserts Joda Time to plugin jar, so the classes will be found at runtime.

Into your **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
   <plugins>

      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.7</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                  <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>

   </plugins>
</build>
```

Then use name-with-dependencies.jar as your plugin file.